# Counter in Node.js

Tags: node.js, counter

I'm trying to make a Node.js counter function which will count in the terminal until I stop it.
However, I'm having a problem with it.

Here's my code:

```js
async function test() {
  var count = 1
  var newcount = count + 1
  var count = newcount
  console.log(count)
}
```

The count stays on **1**.
I know why this is, I just don't know how to fix it.
It stays on 1 because I'm declaring it as 1 every loop.
It does go to 2, but it doesn't go any higher because of what I just said. I can't figure out how to *stop* it from declaring as 1 every loop.

So if anyone could help, that'd be great.

### Edit:

I forgot to put this in my code snippet:

```js
setInterval(test, 10000)
```

Comment: So you aren't exactly looping at all in your code snippet. If you aren't trying to use an actual loop, you could use what @alex-van-steenhoven suggested as an answer and just add a check for your exit command or write a recursive counting function.

Comment: oh yeah i edited my question, i had included a `setInterval` line but forgot to put it in my code snippet on the question. i've updated it now.

Comment: What you are currently doing is just calling a function that sums up to 2 at the end of its operation. Once it's been executed, the `stack` is cleared and it will repeat itself again. So you're simply calling the same thing over and over again not actually doing anything more

Answer (score 1):

First of all why are you using async while you don't need it / use await?

The reason why your function is not working is that you are not looping over your variable.
Your function should look something like this.

```js
function counter() {
  let count = 0
  setInterval(() => {
    count++;
    console.log(count)
  }, 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run the function `test()` it will reset the counter to 1

```js
  var count = 1
```

You should declare the variable outside of the function (global variable) or use a function parameter and returning the new value. Examples would be

```js
// Using a global variable
var count = 1;
function countFunction() {
  var newcount = count + 1;
  count = newcount;
  console.log(count);
}

// To use this inside a setInterval
setInterval(countFunction, 10000);

// Using a function parameter and returning value
var count = 1
function countFunction(countParameter=0) {
  return countParameter+1;
}

count = countFunction(count); // 2
count = countFunction(count); // 3
count = countFunction(count); // 4
count = countFunction(count); // 5

// To use this inside a setInterval
var count=1
setInterval(()=>{count = countFunction(count)}, 10000)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The second code example just constantly returns `2`, and the first code example gives an `INVALID_CALLBACK` error when I call it using `setInterval`.

Comment: @SlendertheBlender, it shouldn't. I added screenshots maybe they help you.

Comment: I see you've also edited the code. I'll try the edited code. Thanks, I would suggest noting edits like I did on my question.